# Doxygen and C function name with modifiers

Tags: c, embedded, doxygen

I'm documenting some embedded C code and some functions have storage modifiers that are specific to the compiler, like so:

```
int chess_storage(x0) firmware_function(unsigned long int chess_storage(a0) param)
```

Because the directive has a parameter, Doxygens interprets the directive as the function name.

The usual solution would be to use `PREDEFINED` directive in the Doxyfile as explained in the [Doxygen Manual:Preprocessing](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) and this [mail list post](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-force-doxygen-to-ignore-compiler-specific-keywords-td2857.html) to completely ignore the storage modifier:

```
PREDEFINED             = chess_storage(x)=
```

The problem with this approach is that the documentation would not be accurate, as the actual function does have that modifier.

I've also tried to use `@fn`, but it didn't work either.

```
/**
 * @fn int firmware_function(unsigned long int param);
 *
 * A C function with a modifier
 *
 * @param param A parameter
 * @return zero.
 */
int chess_storage(x0) firmware_function(unsigned long int chess_storage(a0) param);
```

So the goal here is not to ignore the parameter, but make Doxygen aware that it's just a word.

Comment: As afar as I know this is a newer functionality of c++ (I don't know when it was introduced, might already be a few year ago), that has not, yet, been build-in into doxygen. Maybe best to check and when necessary create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues).

Comment: OK, that was what I was afraid of. Just a heads up, I don't think this is a standard C++ functionality, it's a directive com the Chess compiler from Synopsys. Cheers!

Comment: `chess_storage(x)` might as well be a preprocessor macro with an argument.